# Swapping images only

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, slidetoggle

Problem, I created my wordpress theme with the intended idea of the user hovering over a post link and then the links feature img would swipe in and swipe out.  The code to create the post works, here is what is generated. The problem is that the transition jQuery code I created is not animating the slidetoggle of the images, it is doing the add remove of the class 'selected' properly. Thanks for the help

This is my wrapper

```
<div id="blog-posts">


</div>
```

Inside is where the posts go to.

```
<div id="blog-posts">
  <div class="posts-slider selected">                                       
  <img width="600" height="156" alt="angularjs" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image sel-img" src="http://designsbycamaron.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/angularjs.png">                     
 <div class="slider-content">
  <ul>                                  
     <li><a href="http://designsbycamaron.net/2013/07/new-framework-knowledge/">                                        
     New Framework Knowledge
     </a>  
     </li>
     <li><p>I have been really careful to not add Frameworks that I am not familiar with or have not used extensively</p>
     </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
 div.selected img {
     display: block;
     height: auto;
     position: absolute;
  }

  .slider-content {
     clear: both;
     float: right;
     padding-right: 20px;
     text-align: right;
     width: 350px;
   }
```

Here is my jQuery that is suppose to do the transition.

```
  $('.posts-slider a').mouseover(function(){
$(this).parents('.posts-slider img').slideToggle().siblings('.selected img').slideToggle('slow');
    $(this).parents('.posts-slider').addClass('selected').siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
});
```

You can see a live version of this on [my website](http://designsbycamaron.net).

I figure this is something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the layout of the HTML is not really conducive to an easy solution, however - this should work. Replace your mouseover function to be this:

```
$('.posts-slider a').mouseover(function(){
      var wrapper = $(this).closest('.posts-slider');
      var image = $('img', wrapper);
      $('.posts-slider img').not(image).slideUp();
      image.slideDown();
      $('.posts-slider').removeClass('selected').filter(wrapper).addClass('selected');
});
```

and replace your CSS so that all images are `position:absolute`, not just the ones with a  `.selected` parent.

Comment: ya, I realize that the html is not the best formatted, but when calling posts through wordpress, i didnt find an easier solution. Thanks, gonna try this.